# Printing HTML with Javascript : is not defined error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm working on a website using HTML, PHP and Javascript JQuery
I have a datatable in html where I print my results from a database.
Each row has a delete button, where I call a javascript function.

Now I want to insert a row in that table using javascript, this works, but the problem is how to print the function for the delete button correctly.

The onclick funtion needs to parse the element and the brand name (it's about cars)

The code will explain more:

Datatable :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover roles-table" id="makes">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Merk</th>
                                    <th>Verwijderen</th>

                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <?php $result = $userProfile->getSubBrands($companyId);
                                foreach($result as $subBrand):
                                    ?>
                                    <tr class="role-row" >
                                        <td>
                                            <?php echo htmlentities($subBrand['brand_name']); ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="profile.deleteSubs(this,'<?php echo htmlentities($subBrand['brand_name']); ?>');">
                                                <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Verwijderen </button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php
                                endforeach;
                                ?>

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

How I add my row with jquery (the res comes from JSON result parsing) :

```
t.row.add([
                res.brandName,
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="profile.deleteSubs(this,'+res.brandName+');"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Verwijderen</button>'
            ]).draw();
```

This adds the row, but when I click the button I get the error 
"Uncaught ReferenceError: BMW is not defined" BMW is the name of the brand

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to enclose the `BMW` in quotes.

Comment: What is deleteSubs() ?

Comment: deleteSubs() is just a function that calls an ajax function, nothing special, just parses the element and brand name to ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
t.row.add([
                res.brandName,
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="profile.deleteSubs(this,\''+res.brandName+'\');"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Verwijderen</button>'
            ]).draw();
```

Comment: Awesome that works! Thanks! But now the row doesn't dissapear, element not parsed correctly? 

this is how I hide the row : 

$(element).parents(".role-row").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });